Getting the HTTP response code when running a MS graph API GET call
I am working on a small Graph Project using python.  I have got it to update all of the info i want such as department manager etc, but i cant for the life of me get the statu code form the API call so i can upload our AirTable to say the automation has went as expected (or hasn't)
My call is
response = await graph_client.users.by_user_id("user-ID").get()

I get the following output, and when i print(response) I see the expected data.
INFO:httpx:HTTP Request: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"User-ID" "HTTP/2 200 OK"

